# Shorter Syntax For Cases In Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Say I have something silly like this:

```
data SomeType
    = Unary Int
    | Associative SomeType
    | Binary SomeType SomeType

some_func :: SomeType -> Int
some_func s =
    case s of
        Unary n -> n
        Associative s1 -> some_func s1
        Binary s1 s2 -> some_func s1 + some_func s2
```

Here some_func will look through all SomeTypes in a given SomeType and sum up the Ints of all Unary data constructors. SomeType is a recursive data type.

In these pattern matches I'm repeating `some_func s1`. Is there a way to use @, when, let or anything else to declare `sf1 = some_func s1` and use it in both? Something like this:

```
data SomeType
    = Unary Int
    | Associative SomeType
    | Binary SomeType SomeType

some_func :: SomeType -> Int
some_func s =
    case s of
        Unary n -> n
        Associative s1 -> sf1
        Binary s1 s2 -> sf1 + sf2
        where
            sf1 = some_func s1
            sf2 = some_func s2
```

The problem here is that s1 and s2 are only known in the block after `->` and sf1 can't be calculated.

Comment: What are s1 and s2, I can't see their definition. You got s as parametr, and define after where only sf1 and sf2.

Comment: s1 and s2 are of SomeType, they're from the pattern match in the cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abuse record syntax!

```
data SomeType
    = Unary { u :: Int }
    | Associative { s1 :: SomeType }
    | Binary { s1, s2 :: SomeType }

someFunc :: SomeType -> Int
someFunc s = case s of
    Unary{}       -> u s
    Associative{} -> sf1
    Binary{}      -> sf1 + sf2
  where
    sf1 = someFunc (s1 s)
    sf2 = someFunc (s2 s)
```

Note that different constructors of the same type are allowed to have the *same named fields* in their records. Laziness prevents you from erroring on `sf2` if you go down the `Associative` branch.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most elegant solution, nicely done.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer the question but might solve the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
module SomeType where
import Data.Foldable as F

data SomeType a
    = Unary a
    | Associative (SomeType a)
    | Binary (SomeType a) (SomeType a)
      deriving (Foldable)

some_func :: SomeType Int -> Int
some_func = F.foldl1 (+)
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no: the `s1` in `Associative` is different to the `s1` in `Binary`. The fact that they have the same name is a distraction, because they exist in different contexts.

I guess you could save some typing by using a helper but this doesn't really help encapsulate the repeated logic:

```
some_func :: SomeType -> Int
some_func s = go s
  where go (Unary n) = n
        go (Associative s1) = go s1
        go (Binary s1 s2) = go s1 + go s2
```

Comment: `some_func s = go s` - I see no purpose in writing this in terms of `go`, why not just pattern match directly at the `some_func` level? This was only suggested to "save some typing"? I'd discourage using a helper function that adds no value, even if it saves a few keystrokes.

Comment: @DanBurton, the "I guess" was very reluctant. I agree that it is almost entirely pointless.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this'll make it shorter in this specific case, but in the more general case, you should check out [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.3176). For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, DeriveDataTypeable, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Generics

data SomeType
    = Unary Int
    | Associative SomeType
    | Binary SomeType SomeType
    deriving (Data, Typeable, Show)

flatten_sometype x@(Unary _) = x
flatten_sometype (Associative s) = s
flatten_sometype (Binary (Unary a) (Unary b)) = Unary $ a + b

some_func2 = let Unary n = everywhere (mkT flatten_sometype)
             in  n
```

As you can see, by using `everywhere`, I need only specify a local transformation - SYB takes care of all the recursion. Where this really comes in handy is when you have multiple types involved; SYB will happily tunnel through types you *aren't* transforming and transform their arguments as well. Be careful how much you use it though - it can lead to a ton of GC churn if overused.

Comment: what's the type signature of flatten_sometype?

Comment: @AramKocharyan: `SomeType → SomeType`. But mind you, it isn't total function.

Comment: The type of `some_func2` is also `SomeType -> SomeType`, right? Whereas the original `some_func` was `SomeType -> Int`. I take it the desired result is in a `Unary` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to write it should simply be pattern-matching:

```
some_func :: SomeType -> Int
some_func (Unary n) = n
some_func (Associative s) = some_func s
some_func (Binary s1 s2) = (some_func s1) + (some_func s2)
```

There is still repetition of the pieces, so it probably doesn't answer your question ... Maybe something involving defining `some_func` in terms of `fmap some_func`?